# CM106 USB Audio Device v0d8c p0102 has no control for headphone

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

**Logilink 7.1 UA0099 CM106 USB Audio Device v0d8c p0102** shows  no headphone.

In `modinfo snd-usb-audio` there is no entry for this vendor, hence no options.

There are no headphones in `alsamixer` neither in `pulseaudio` and therefore also no chance to lower the speaker volume down and use the headphone to not disturb my environment some time.

A workaround is with my onboard sound and `alsa_in` and not use the USB Device at all then. Since this is a common chipset, I guess, its just a simple overlooked by me switch.

Has anybody configured a card like this with running/showing headphones?

Answer (score 0):

The CM106 hardware has no separate headphones volume control.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it, the CM106USB selects the front speakers for headphone output and does not mute anything (I have no idea why my headphone output is dead under basically all circumstances).

The control word written to the respective register in `snd_usb_cm106_boot_quirk` is 0x8004 and I believe that in order to have the headphone switch off the loudspeaker ports it would have to be 0x0004 instead.

Haven't figured out yet where else this register might get written to.

Comment: As for me, the headphones have the same output as the 2.1 connector. But no slider to control it. Since I have a sound-system connected at the 2.1 connector, I just switch it off and can listen with the headphones in headphone connector.  Bad , but working solution.